# Cordova iOS app: Console.log line numbers aren't shown

Tags: javascript, cordova, console, numbers, line

I'm writing a Cordova application, targeting iOS.  I have many `Console.log("foo")`; statements, but when I'm debugging the app it won't show the line number that the Console statement originated from.  It *always* shows the same line number, generated by `Cordova.js`.

For example, if I have a `Console.log("foo");` statement on line 256, then the expected message in the Javascript console should be:

```
foo   index.js:256
```

However, instead it always outputs:

```
foo   cordova.js:1413
```

Even if I generate a source map (I'm using Webpack) it doesn't really help.  Console statements that are written outside of a function are shown with their correct line number, but ones within functions or event handlers are not shown.

This example...

```
Console.log("test");
function testFunction() {
 Console.log("within a function");
};
```

...Will generate:

```
   test                index.js:1
   within a function   cordova.js:1413
```

Even when the app is run in the browser only (and not in the iOS simulator) I get the same result in Chrome as I did in Safari.  It's frustrating me that I can't see the original line numbers, as it is preventing me from debugging properly.

Comment: Not certain why someone flagged/down voted this.  I am experiencing the same thing on newly installed MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 running Safari: 16.3.  Have you found a solution for this?